# How to get the nth highest entry in each group of mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in MySQL and I've stumbled upon this for the past few days now.

Let's say I have a country table as seen below:

```
code    name            continent       Population
ABW Aruba               North America   103000
AFG Afghanistan         Asia            22720000
AGO Angola              Africa          12878000
AIA Anguilla            North America   8000
ALB Albania             Europe          3401200
AND Andorra             Europe          78000
ARG Argentina           South America   37032000
```

This table has information of continents and population of each country.

How do I find the country with nth highest population in each continent?

For a specific scenario, How do I find the country with the thrid highest population in each continent?

I checked many SO questions, including this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210556/mysql-get-nth-highest-value-for-each-group-in-a-table). But could not find the answer for this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do this is using variables.

```
select code,name,continent,population 
from (
select c.*, 
@prevPopulation:=@curPopulation,
@curPopulation:=population,
@prevContinent:=@curContinent,
@curContinent:=continent,
case when @curContinent = @prevContinent and @prevPopulation <> @curPopulation then @rn:=@rn+1
     when @curContinent = @prevContinent and @prevPopulation = @curPopulation then @rn:=@rn
else @rn:=1 end as rank
from country c,
(select @rn := 0, @curContinent := '',@prevContinent := '', @curPopulation:=0,@prevPopulation:=0) r
order by continent,population desc
) x
where rank = 3 --replace it with the nth highest value needed
```

This query uses 4 variables

1) @curContinent which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the `select` assigns the current row's continent.

2) @prevContinent which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the `select` sets it to @curContinent value (which is an empty string initially).

3) @curPopulation which is initially set to 0. Thereafter the `select` assigns the current row's population.

4) @prevPopulation which is initially set to 0. Thereafter the `select` sets it to  the @curPopulation (which is 0 for the first time and so on).

`order by` clause is important here to desingate the current and previous rows based on continent and population. This would handle ties  too as it would assign the same rank to all the countries within a continent with the same population.

Run the inner query initially to see how the variables are set, which would clarify things for you.

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/STPHL54622)

Answer (score 3):

```
      with result as 
      (
        select code,name,continent,population,dense_rank() over( order by population ) as rnk 
        from dbo.country
       )
      select population,continent from result where rnk=3 group by continent,population  ;
```

If you want the 2nd highest population then enter the rnk in where clause as 2 and so on ..

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. More clean cut then the others.

Comment: This is a T-SQL syntax, if you are using mysql (as op asked) just replace the result table alias in `from result where` with the first subquery at `with result as (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no countries have the same population, then one method is to count the number of countries that have the same or higher population and see when the count is 3:

```
select c.*
from country c
where (select count(*)
       from country c2
       where c2.continent = c.continent and c2.population >= c.population
      ) = 3;
```

Comment: Granted this is a pretty tricksy thing to do, but assuming that no 2 countries in a continent have the same, clearly estimated, popualtion seems like such a kludge.   With all due respect, sir.   That having been said ... I've not thought of a better solution.

Comment: One alternative is to use variables.  Or a database that properly supports `row_number()`, `rank()`, etc.